# Cannot resolve constructor Builder()

Tags: android, okhttp

Using okhttp
I'm getting a cannot resolve constructor error on the line new Request.Builder()

```
public final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
        }

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
}
```

Have no idea why I'm getting this error. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:my imports

```
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
```

Comment: Where's the error trace?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya What?

Comment: i'm a beginner to android studio please help @YosiPramajaya

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces  It is best practise to post your stack trace to give others the best chance to help you, as just saying 'I have x error' isn't very helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: @j.edgar please post the imports so that we can see which `Request` class you are using. Thanks

Comment: @uprightbassfan78 the app it not installing. It's showing the error on the editor itself

Comment: Perhaps you need `import okhttp3.Request`;